# Prove that $|z_{1}+z_{2}| < |1+\overline{z_{1}}\cdot z_{2}|\;$ if $|z_{1}| < 1$ and $|z_{2}| < 1$.

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-explanation

Given $z_{1},z_{2} \in \mathbb{C}$

Prove that $|z_{1}+z_{2}| < |1+\overline{z_{1}}\cdot z_{2}|\;$, if $|z_{1}| < 1$ and $|z_{2}| < 1$.

My Professor gave my classmates and I, the following answer:

$|z_{1} + z_{2}| \leq |z_{1} + z_{2}|\cdot |\overline{z_{1}}|\;$ $\Leftarrow$ The part I'm having trouble with

$|z_{1} + z_{2}|\cdot |\overline{z_{1}}| = |z_{1}\overline{z_{1}} + z_{2}\overline{z_{1}}| = ||z_{1}|^{2} + z_{2}\overline{z_{1}}| < |1+\overline{z_{1}}z_{2}|$

$\therefore |z_{1}+z_{2}| < |1+\overline{z_{1}}z_{2}|$

I don't understand why the line highlighted is correct.

Since $|\overline{z_{1}}| = |z_{1}| < 1$, $\;|\overline{z_{1}}|\cdot  |z_{1} + z_{2}|< 1\cdot |z_{1} + z_{2}|$ which contradicts the proof above.

If my reasoning is correct, How could I prove this statement?

Comment: I disagree with the solution presented in the question. We have actually $|z_1+z_2| \ge |z_1+z_2| \times |\overline{z_1}|$. Atila Correia's solution below is correct.

Answer (score 4):

The inequality $\lvert z_1 + z_2\rvert \leq \lvert z_1 + z_2\rvert \cdot \lvert \overline{z_{1}} \rvert$ is obviously wrong. Take for example $z_1 = 0$ and $z_2 \neq 0$.

Now coming back to the initial problem, you can prove that for any reals $0 \le a,b \lt 1$, the inequality $a+b \lt 1+ab$ holds. This can be done for example by studying the real map
$$f_a(x) = ax -a -x +1$$ on the interval $[0,1]$, or by noticing that $(1-a)(1-b) \gt 0$.

Applying that to $a= \lvert z_1 \rvert^2$ and $b = \lvert z_2 \rvert^2$, you get the inequality

$$\lvert z_1 \rvert^2 + \lvert z_2 \rvert^2 \lt 1 + \lvert z_1 \rvert^2 \lvert z_2 \rvert^2$$

Adding $z_1 \overline{z_2} + z_2 \overline{z_1}$ (which is a real number) on both side of the inequality, you get the desired inequality

$$\lvert z_1 + z_2 \rvert^2 \lt \lvert 1 + \overline{z_1} z_2 \rvert^2.$$

Comment: I'm really thankful for you answer! However, could you please explain the last step: $1 + |z_{1}|^{2}|z_{2}|^{2} + z_{1}\overline{z_{2}} + \overline{z_{1}}z_{2} = |1 + \overline{z_{1}}z_{2}|^{2}

Comment: Remember that for any $Z \in \mathbb C$, you have $\lvert Z \rvert^2 =Z \overline Z$. Just apply that to $Z=1+\overline{z_1}z_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Square both sides:
\begin{align*}
|z + w| < |1 + \overline{z}w| & \Longleftrightarrow |z + w|^{2} < |1 + \overline{z}w|^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (z + w)(\overline{z} + \overline{w}) < (1 + \overline{z}w)(1 + z\overline{w})\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z\overline{z} + z\overline{w} + \overline{z}w + w\overline{w} < 1 + z\overline{w} + \overline{z}w + z\overline{z}w\overline{w}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |z|^{2} + |w|^{2} < 1 + |z|^{2}|w|^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |z|^{2}(|w|^{2} - 1) + 1 - |w|^{2} > 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (1 - |z|^{2})(1 - |w|^{2}) > 0
\end{align*}

which clearly holds based on the assumption that $|z| < 1$ and $|w| < 1$.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The professor proof is wrong as observed at the beggining of mathcounterexamples.net's answer.

Your reasoning is almost correct:

"
Since $|\overline{z_{1}}| = |z_{1}| < 1$, $\;|\overline{z_{1}}|\cdot  |z_{1} + z_{2}|\color{red}{<} 1\cdot |z_{1} + z_{2}|$ which contradicts the proof above."

Since you're multiplying by $|z_1+z_2|$ and it could be $0$ you can't assure that the **strict** inequality is preserved. It should be $\le$.

By the way, that's not only point where your professor went wrong:

From $\left|z_1\right|^2<1$ you cannot conclude that $\left|\left|z_1\right|^2 + \overline{z_1}z_2\right| < \left|1+\overline{z_1}z_2\right|$.